# How to make arrays of scraped data from multiple pages the same length in python?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to apply a singular data point to multiple rows in my dataframe (e.g., cst_n & vv1 below), so the output in excel looks like:

> [image]

My code intends to scrape election results from multiple pages on a public government database. Each page it runs through has a different amount of data available (e.g., page1 has 5 candidates, page2 has 9). I tried to multiply the cst_n and vv1 variables by the length of pty_n within the for loop scraping these pages. Not sure why I keep getting a "ValueError: arrays must all be same length" when running this code:

```html
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

from time import sleep
from random import randint

constituencies = []
candidates = []
partynames = []
votes = []
partyvoteshare = []
totalvotes = [] 

for page in range(100,326):

    page = requests.get("https://results.aec.gov.au/24310/Website/HouseDivisionPage-24310-" + str(page) + ".htm", verify=False)

    page.encoding = page.apparent_encoding

    if not page:
        pass
    
    else:

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    
        aust_tbody = soup.find_all('tbody')

        sleep(randint(2,10))

        for container in aust_tbody:

            #### CANDIDATES ####
            can = container.find_all('td', {'headers':'fpCan'})
            for data in can:
                can2 = str(data.get_text())
                candidates.append(can2)

            #### PARTY NAMES ####
            partyn = container.find_all('td', {'headers':'fpPty'})
            for data in partyn:
                partyn2 = str(data.get_text())
                partynames.append(partyn2)

            #### VOTES ####
            votec = container.find_all('td', {'headers':'fpVot'}, class_='row-right')
            for data in votec:
                votec2 = str(data.get_text())
                votes.append(votec2)

            #### PARTY VOTE SHARE ####
            ptysh = container.find_all('td', {'headers':'fpPct'}, class_='row-right')
            for data in ptysh:
                ptysh2 = str(data.get_text())
                partyvoteshare.append(ptysh2)

            #### TOTAL  VOTES ####`
            for location in container.find_all('tr',class_='total'):
                finvotes = location.find('td', {'headers':'fpVot'}, class_='row-right')
                for data in finvotes:
                    fvot = str(data.get_text())
                    fvot2 = [fvot]
                    fvot3 = fvot2 * len(partyn)
                    votes.append(fvot3)

        #### CONSTITUENCY NAMES ####
        constit = soup.find('h1',id_='StandardHeading')
        if constit is not None:
            constit = constit.get_text()
        else:
            constit = "N/A"
            
        constit_list = [constit]
        constit_list2 = constit_list * len(partyn)
        constituencies.append(constit_list2)
       

aust19 = pd.DataFrame({
'cst_n': constituencies,
'can': candidates,
'pty_n': partynames,
'pv1': votes,
'pvs1': partyvoteshare,
'vv1': totalvotes 
})

print(aust19)

aust19.to_csv('aust19.csv')
```

Can anyone help with the #### TOTAL VOTES #### and #### CONSTITUENCIES #### segments of my code? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The data you get is not the same length. Try row by row.
And try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils, req

html = req.get('https://results.aec.gov.au/24310/Website/HouseDivisionPage-24310-101.htm')
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
table = doc.select('table#fp').getTable()
print (table)

utils.save2csv('data_2.csv', table)


# Or
table = doc.select('table#fp').trs.children.text
table = doc.select('table#fp').selects('tr').children.text
```